# Reuse inflated views

Tags: android

I am building a complex view based on dynamic data. Depending on the number of data elements in collections I am adding more views. Each of these subviews are complex and get inflated in the loop through the data collection.

This is of course inefficient and I would like to figure out a way to inflate the subview only once and then reusing them instead. Is this possible somehow?

PS: I do not want to build up the subviews in code (I know I could) because that would make things even messier due to the complexities and number of subviews, but if the performance would increase considerably I might take a look at that.

PPS: There is no visible performance problem but traceview that most of the time is spent inflating and if I can make it faster I would love to ;-)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am with the exact same problem and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: No... unfortunately not. I pretty much gave up on this. The best I came up with was a view created from code and caching that.. but thats ugly to write and maintain.

Comment: I see. Thanks for replying though Manfred!

Answer (score 2):

you can check out the Google IO Session entitled 'The world of ListView'.

It explains very nicely how to prevent inflating the same view again and again, and how to reuse a particular view if it has been already inflated earlier.

Here is the link.

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

You can either download the .pdf file or view the video.

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Mahendra Liya.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but in my case I am NOT dealing with listviews. I have applied that pattern fine on my plain listview pages but in this case the "lists" are build up by dynamically inserting inflated views and there are a three different ones in the page. Listviews dont work well if you have multiple ones on the same page and also have the wrong scrolling behaviour. I need to scroll the whole page. All the rendering works and behaviour works fine .. it just inflates each view multiple times.